# Plotting a "Competitive Landscape" Business Grid in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts

**Question:** Is there a way to create a graph similar to the one below?

> [image]

**Some ideas:**

- Each business is a point on the plane $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.
- Each point on the plane can be represented as an image in Mathematica (I assume).

**Attempt:** Perhaps a good place to start is `ListPlot`

```
ListPlot[{1, 1, -1} -> {"Freindster", "LinkedIn", "Interface Software"}]
```

Here's not clear how to (i) add pictures as labels; (ii) add commentary and (iii) let the X-axis range from $-1$ to $1$ as in the LinkedIn graph.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and what you have problems with.

Comment: Wow, *Friendster*? And it was in *beta*? Is this picture from the 1960's or something?

Comment: @march, 2004 if I'm reading https://ourstory.linkedin.com correctly.

Comment: george, you might want to post an image without the  "CONFIDENTIAL"  marking.

Comment: @kglr May be the "CONFIDENTIAL" marking as one of question's requirements.

Comment: @Anton, may well be:)

Comment: Take a look at `Graphics` and `Inset` and if you get stuck, let us know where. Also, prepare a minimal data to work with in that case. Without details it is only a question about basic `Graphics/Inset` `Arrow` etc. so I will put it on hold now.